# c++ unhandled exception. what's going on?

Tags: c++, crash, unhandled-exception

i'm trying to make a Shannon code maker from input text, and i have some troubles...

so, there is some simple shit-code

```
int main()
{
    string x="this is very big text.";
    int temp;
    int N = x.length();
    int *mass = new int [N];
```

then counting symbols in text;

then counting symbols that used from ASCII table;

creating new 2 massives with symbols and counters of symbol, but their dimention is quite smaller;

delete old char massive by `delete mass;`

sort 'em by counters and counting their cumulative probability;

```
double * cumulative = new double (k);
            double temp=int_mass[0];
            cumulative[0]=0;
            for (int i=1; i<k; i++)
        {
            temp=int_mass[i-1];
            cumulative[i]=cumulative[i-1]+temp/N;
        }
```

cout'ing all 3 massives

```
double a,b,n;
n=N;
for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
{
    b=int_mass[i];
    b/=n;
    cout<<char_mass[i]<<" ";
    cout<<b<<" ";                       //**__**__**
    cout<<cumulative[i]<<endl;
}
```

so, i have some troubles.
if text is small, then i catch unhandled exception at praogram's termination.
if text is big, about 100+ symbols, i have exception at **__**__**.

do you have any suggestions, why it happens?

sorry for big code, it my first commit on StackOverFlow.

Comment: `delete mass;` is undefined behaviour. Just another reason why things like `std::vector` are safer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[]` instead of `()` to [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) arrays:

```
double * cumulative = new double [k];
                                 ^ ^
```

`(k)` just makes a single place in memory and initializes it to `k` instead of making an array with size `k`.

Use `[]` for deleting arrays:

```
delete [] mass;
       ^^
```

You're using `k`, but I can't see where you initialized it ?!

```
for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
```

It's better to use `std::vector` instead of self defined arrays to avoid above problems.

Comment: "have another code"!? Urrrgh. https://twitter.com/tinkertim/status/266476654887583745